# UL+CSS for grid layout

Tags: html, css, layout

I have a server-generated html like:

```
<ul>
    <li><!-- few nested elements that form a block --></li>
    <li><!-- few nested elements that form anaother block --></li>
    <li><!-- etc, X times --></li>
</ul>
```

All blocks have known width 200px and unknown height. I want `<li>` to be arranged in table-like fashion like this:

[image]

What I have for now is following css:

```
li {
    display: block;
    width: 200px;
    float: left;
    margin: 10px;
}
```

All is fine except that columns don't get equal height. And in example above block #4 “snatch” at #1 and the result isn't what I'm trying to achieve:

[image]

Is there any pure-CSS cross-browser way that will allow grid layout I want and will not enforce markup change?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

[Inline blocks](http://blog.mozilla.com/webdev/2009/02/20/cross-browser-inline-block/) could perhaps be useful here.

Comment: +1, but mind IE7, who only allows inline-block for naturally inline elements.

Comment: Great link! Exactly what I need.

Comment: You will most likely then run in problems with inline white space. In this case, look at this thread over at doctype.com: http://doctype.com/csss-inlineblock-white-space-between-items

Answer (score 4):

In your example you seem to want to give each row the same height of the largest li in that row. If this height is variable what you want is only possible with nth-child:

```
li:nth-child(3n+0) { clear: left; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Option 1: Give them explicit heights

Options 2: Use [nth-child](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#nth-child-pseudo) (which has limited support)