# How to lay-out list items like a grid with CSS and HTML?

Tags: html, css

I have a div block which does *not* have a fixed width.

Inside, I have an `<ul> <li>..</li>` block with 11 items.
I would like these `<li>` items to be listed inside the div, all with equal widths like this:

```
##item##  ##item##  ##item##
##item##  ##item##  ##item##
##item##  ##item##  ##item##
##item##            ##item##
```

However, I can't sort it out at all.

I tried float left and right but the central 3 elements will not be centered.

What can I do to get this working?

Thanks!

Comment: Could you include the relevant markup and CSS? You probably just need to specify a width for each `LI`.

Answer (score 32):

The ["Inline Blocks" link](http://blog.mozilla.org/webdev/2009/02/20/cross-browser-inline-block/) that [Jordan posted](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14885204/1430996) is a great resource, particularly when it comes to older browser support. For quick reference for others landing on this page off of google, the basic css for creating a centered, inline-block grid is:

```
ul {
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
}

li {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

Answer (score 30):

The simplest solution is to use [CSS columns](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/columns):

http://jsfiddle.net/6tD2D/ (prefixes not included)

```
ul {
    columns: 3;
}

<ul>
    <li>a</li>
    <li>b</li>
    <li>c</li>
    <li>d</li>
    <li>e</li>
    <li>f</li>
    <li>g</li>
    <li>h</li>
    <li>i</li>
    <li>j</li>
    <li>k</li>
</ul>
```

This will equalize the columns as best it can.  However, if there aren't enough elements to be perfectly equal, it will start removing them from the right instead of the center.

Comment: the jsfiddle example does not work in my chrome only 1 column

Comment: Nor does it work with IEOld. See bottom of https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/columns for compatibility.

Comment: Is there a simple solution like this, but where you want the elements to go out right (horizontally) first, and not downwards?

Answer (score 4):

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2712350/ulcss-for-grid-layout) StackOverflow question, [Inline Blocks](http://blog.mozilla.org/webdev/2009/02/20/cross-browser-inline-block/) may be just what you need.

Oh, and if you aren't implementing it already, be sure to look into [CSS Grids](http://css-tricks.com/dont-overthink-it-grids/), too. If you don't want to build a CSS grid yourself, [this one](http://cssgrid.net/) is fantastic.

Answer (score 1):

### CSS

```
ul {
  display: grid; 
  grid-auto-columns: 1fr; 
  grid-auto-rows: 1fr; 
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr; 
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr; 
  gap: 0px 0px; 
  grid-template-areas: 
    "col1-item1 col2-item1 col3-item1"
    "col1-item2 col2-item2 col3-item2"
    "col1-item3 col2-item3 col3-item3"
    "col1-item4 col2-item3 col3-item4"; 
}

/* Assign a class to each li */
    /* Column 1 */
.col1-item1 { grid-area: col1-item1; }
.col1-item2 { grid-area: col1-item2; }
.col1-item3 { grid-area: col1-item3; }
.col1-item4 { grid-area: col1-item4; }
    /* Column 2 */
.col2-item1 { grid-area: col2-item1; }
.col2-item2 { grid-area: col2-item2; }
.col2-item3 { grid-area: col2-item3; }
    /* Column 3 */
.col3-item1 { grid-area: col3-item1; }
.col3-item2 { grid-area: col3-item2; }
.col3-item3 { grid-area: col3-item3; }
.col3-item4 { grid-area: col3-item4; }
```

### HTML

```
<ul>
    <!-- Column 1 -->
    <li class="col1-item1">col1 item 1</li>
    <li class="col1-item2">col1 item 2</li>
    <li class="col1-item3">col1 item 3</li>
    <li class="col1-item4">col1 item 4</li>

    <!-- Column 2 -->
    <li class="col2-item1">col2 item 1</li>
    <li class="col2-item2">col2 item 2</li>
    <li class="col2-item3">col2 item 3</li>

    <!-- Column 3 -->
    <li class="col3-item1">col3 item 1</li>
    <li class="col3-item2">col3 item 2</li>
    <li class="col3-item3">col3 item 3</li>
    <li class="col3-item4">col3 item 4</li>
</ul>
```

Here is the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/omarjuvera/p3wajehs/2/

And also you can run the code here

```css
ul {
  display: grid; 
  grid-auto-columns: 1fr; 
  grid-auto-rows: 1fr; 
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr; 
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr; 
  gap: 0px 0px; 
  grid-template-areas: 
    "col1-item1 col2-item1 col3-item1"
    "col1-item2 col2-item2 col3-item2"
    "col1-item3 col2-item3 col3-item3"
    "col1-item4 col2-item3 col3-item4"; 
}

/* Assign a class to each li */
  /* Column 1 */
.col1-item1 { grid-area: col1-item1; }
.col1-item2 { grid-area: col1-item2; }
.col1-item3 { grid-area: col1-item3; }
.col1-item4 { grid-area: col1-item4; }
  /* Column 2 */
.col2-item1 { grid-area: col2-item1; }
.col2-item2 { grid-area: col2-item2; }
.col2-item3 { grid-area: col2-item3; }
  /* Column 3 */
.col3-item1 { grid-area: col3-item1; }
.col3-item2 { grid-area: col3-item2; }
.col3-item3 { grid-area: col3-item3; }
.col3-item4 { grid-area: col3-item4; }
```

```html
<ul>
  <!-- Column 1 -->
  <li class="col1-item1">col1 item 1</li>
  <li class="col1-item2">col1 item 2</li>
  <li class="col1-item3">col1 item 3</li>
  <li class="col1-item4">col1 item 4</li>

  <!-- Column 2 -->
  <li class="col2-item1">col2 item 1</li>
  <li class="col2-item2">col2 item 2</li>
  <li class="col2-item3">col2 item 3</li>

  <!-- Column 3 -->
  <li class="col3-item1">col3 item 1</li>
  <li class="col3-item2">col3 item 2</li>
  <li class="col3-item3">col3 item 3</li>
  <li class="col3-item4">col3 item 4</li>
</ul>
```