# CSS - Possible to reflow checkboxes in columns?

Tags: html, css

Is it possible to reflow a dynamic/unknown number of checkboxes into columns horizontally as the height of the container changes?  Here is a simple diagram of what I mean:

**Height = 180px (20px * 9 checkboxes):**

```
[ ] Checkbox 1
[ ] Checkbox 2
[ ] Checkbox 3
[ ] Checkbox 4
[ ] Checkbox 5
[ ] Checkbox 6
[ ] Checkbox 7
[ ] Checkbox 8
[ ] Checkbox 9
```

**Height = 140px (20px * 7 checkboxes):**

```
[ ] Checkbox 1    [ ] Checkbox 8
[ ] Checkbox 2    [ ] Checkbox 9
[ ] Checkbox 3
[ ] Checkbox 4
[ ] Checkbox 5
[ ] Checkbox 6
[ ] Checkbox 7
```

**Height = 100px (20px * 5 checkboxes):**

```
[ ] Checkbox 1    [ ] Checkbox 6
[ ] Checkbox 2    [ ] Checkbox 7
[ ] Checkbox 3    [ ] Checkbox 8
[ ] Checkbox 4    [ ] Checkbox 9
[ ] Checkbox 5
```

As the container element's height shrinks, the checkbox elements would spill horizontally into a new column.

**NOTE:**  I'm well aware that I can create my own columns programmatically, and I'm just looking to see if this is possible with *pure HTML/CSS.*

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to lay-out list items like a grid with CSS and HTML?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14885026/how-to-lay-out-list-items-like-a-grid-with-css-and-html)

Comment: @cimmanon: This is a different problem.  That question answers how to make a variable *height* collection of items given a static *width*.  This question asks how to make a variable *width* collection of items based on a static *height*.  Basically, it's the complete opposite.

Comment: Have you tried *anything*?  You haven't even provided basic markup.

Comment: @cimmanon: I don't think providing markup for a basic list of checkboxes helps clarify the question at all, but if you insist: http://jsfiddle.net/7HPZT/.  And yes, I currently do this in PHP, because I don't know how to do it (or even if it can be done) in pure CSS.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have 2 options available to you.

http://codepen.io/cimmanon/pen/GvmIs

## Multi-column Module

Of the two options, this one has the widest browser support.  You have to define in advance how wide the columns should be.

```
ul {
  height: 25%;
  columns: 10em;
  column-fill: auto;
}
```

http://caniuse.com/#feat=multicolumn

## Flexbox

Flexbox support is rather poor since it just recently went CR, and the subset of browsers that support wrapping is very low (currently only Opera, Chrome, and IE10+ support it).  All you have to specify is the height of the container and it will do the rest for you.

```
ul {
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  -webkit-flex-flow: column wrap;
  -ms-flex-flow: column wrap;
  flex-flow: column wrap;
  height: 25%;
}
@supports (flex-wrap: wrap) {
  ul {
    display: flex;
  }
}
```

http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox (IE10 is the only browser listed as having *partial support* that supports wrapping)

Comment: Thanks, flexbox seems to be what I'm after.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this css.  Here for example you would have six columns in the width of your div.

```css
.columns {
    -moz-column-count: 6;
    -webkit-column-count: 6;
    column-count: 6;
}
```

Set the columns class to your wrapping element.

```html
<div class="columns">
    <input type="checkbox" />
    <input type="checkbox" />
    <input type="checkbox" />
    <input type="checkbox" />
    ...
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, but this answer would make the # of columns static.  I want the number of columns to vary based on the height of the container.

Comment: Not really.  It would divide the div up into columns, each the same height as the container, with a width a sixth of the container.  If you only have a small number of checkboxes they would all be in one column, as you described.

Comment: Unless you mean that you don't want an upper bound on the number of columns?  You want potentially infinite columns?

Comment: Yes, there is no upper bound on the number of checkboxes (dynamic content), so there would also be no bound on the number of columns.  But I would like a static height container.  I've played around with this a bit and can *almost* get what I want if I [specify a height along with the column-count and overflow-x auto](http://jsfiddle.net/kD6jE/1/), but I'm not a fan of how it handles long, unbroken labels.  I'll admit, I'm surprised that it flowed to > 4 columns even with `column-count: 4`.